# Understanding currying functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm new to Javascript and Typescript and i find it incredibly difficult to understand typescript, in particularly currying functions and arrow syntax.

All this while I've been using the syntax, from Java for functions:

```
function(param) {
   ..dosomething..
   .
}
```

and starting javascript lead to arrow syntax functions which i find difficult to understand. In typescript i come across currying where i have examples shown below:

```
const operationOnTwoNumbers = f => x => y => f(x,y)

const multiply = operationOnTwoNumbers((x,y) => x*y)

const double = multiply(2)

[5,8,3,1,7,6,2].map(double)
```

I wasn't provided with a lecture of that much detail but according to my slides, it says that multiply is a curried function.

First and foremost, i want to know how do i interpret the operationOnTwoNumbers arrow syntax function. For now, i interpret it as such:

**operationOnTwoNumbers** is a **function** that takes in **f as an argument**, and returns a function that takes **x as an argument** that returns a function that takes **y as an argument** that returns a function that **does something to x and y.**

Am i correct with the interpretation? Would like some feedback on it.

Now for the multiply curried function. My interpretation would be:

**multiply** is a function that **takes operationOnTwoNumbers as a function**, that **operationOnTwoNumbers take (x,y)** as an argument and **returns a function** that multiplies x and y.

I'm pretty sure my interpretation of these are wrong in a way but i cant seem to understand the syntax. The resource I'm provided with didn't explain much and i tried googling up only to find that I'm getting more confused.

Would really appreciate some help on this, that is for my understanding.

Comment: Please note that you're not using TypeScript in the provided example - only ES6, which is basically a newer version of JavaScript. I might come up with a more detailed explanation later on when I have time.

Comment: As a JS beginner, maybe you'd be better off staying away from currying for a while. I personally think it's an rather ugly manner of dealing with functions that's difficult to maintain.

Comment: If you're not using typescript, you will get an error on your `const double = multiply(2)[5,8,3,1,7,6,2].map(double)` ... because it's trying to access the index of a function... and typescript does not necessarily require any type notation...

Comment: If you enter your function into the [online babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/) you get a non-ES6 version that you might find easier to read. A lot of this is just syntax shorthand.

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` in chrome snippets... `Exception: TypeError: multiply(...)[2] is undefined` in Firefox scratchpad...

Comment: @CodyG. - ...and this is why I don't rely on ASI. :-)

Comment: @CodyG. - The same problem [exists in TypeScript as well](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20operationOnTwoNumbers%20%3D%20f%20%3D%3E%20x%20%3D%3E%20y%20%3D%3E%20f(x%2Cy)%0A%0Aconst%20multiply%20%3D%20operationOnTwoNumbers((x%2Cy)%20%3D%3E%20x*y)%0A%0Aconst%20double%20%3D%20multiply(2)%0A%0A%5B5%2C8%2C3%2C1%2C7%2C6%2C2%5D.map(double)).

Comment: Apparently so, I guess I was thinking typescript had a https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unexpected-multiline option

Comment: And my coworkers don't understand why I go in and put semi-colons everywhere... D: (Not randomly, just when I touch that code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's add some missing semicolons, since without them that code fails in an obscure way (ASI won't add a `;` between `multiply(2)` and `[5,8...` because taken together they're syntactically-valid, though logically nonsensical). Let's also add a `console.log` on the last line:

```
const operationOnTwoNumbers = f => x => y => f(x,y);
const multiply = operationOnTwoNumbers((x,y) => x*y);
const double = multiply(2);
console.log([5,8,3,1,7,6,2].map(double));
```

(You've said you're very new to JavaScript and TypeScript. I strongly recommend **not** relying on ASI. Put `;` at the ends of all statements that aren't flow-control structures ending in blocks. So you'd have one in the places above, and you wouldn't have one on [say] a `while (condition) { ... }` statement.)

> operationOnTwoNumbers is a function that takes in f as an argument, and returns a function that takes x as an argument that returns a function that takes y as an argument that returns a function that does something to x and y.
>
> Am i correct with the interpretation?

Very nearly. *"...that returns a function that takes y as an argument that returns a function that does something to x and y."* isn't correct, it should be *"...that returns the result of calling `f` passing in `x` and `y`."* (Also, technically, `f`, `x`, and `y` are *parameters*, not arguments¹, but it's very common to call them arguments and you're not likely to run into much trouble doing it.) So the full explanation is: "`operationOnTwoNumbers` is a function that takes in `f` as an argument, and returns a function that takes `x` as an argument that returns a function that takes `y` as an argument that returns the result of calling `f` passing in `x` and `y`."

It may help to see the equivalent non-arrow version (since those functions aren't using any of the features of arrow functions other than conciseness):

```
const operationOnTwoNumbers = function(f) {
    return function(x) {
        return function(y) {
            return f(x,y);
        };
    };
};
```

> multiply is a function that takes operationOnTwoNumbers as a function, that operationOnTwoNumbers take (x,y) as an argument and returns a function that multiplies x and y.

Not quite, `multiply` is the *result* of calling `operationOnTwoNumbers` and passing in a function, `(x, y) => x * y` (this becomes the `f` in `operationOnTwoNumbers`). So `multiply` is the function created by `operationOnTwoNumbers` that accepts `x`.

Then `double` is the result of calling `multiply` with `2`, so `2` becomes `x` and `double` is the function that accepts `y`. So for instance, if we do `double(3)`, then `3` is the `y` and since `x` is `2` and `f` is `(x, y) => x * y`, the result of calling `double(3)` is `6`.

Then the `map` call calls `double` for each entry in the array, returning a new array with each value doubled.

---

¹ *parameter* vs. *argument*: A function declares a *parameter*; when you *call* a function, you supply an argument for that parameter. For example:

```
function example(v) {
    return v * 2;
}
console.log(example(7));
```

In `example`, `v` is a parameter (specifically a *formal parameter*). In the call `example(7)`, `7` is the argument for the `v` parameter.

Comment: I find myself looking at these kind of functions and wondering *"whats wrong with just writing it the easily understandable/longhand way"*? To quote one of (IMO) the most sensible people in computing Martin Fowler *"Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand."*

Comment: @T.J. Crowder thank you for your time typing this detailed explanation! Much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: @Liam - Currying can be very powerful. But it's important to write it as clearly as possible, commenting it if necessary. :-)